# Is declspec(align()) still supported on Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio

C++ has a new standard way of specifying alignment - using alignas. And Microsoft documentation suggests replacing declspec(align()) with alignas from Visual Studio 2015 onwards

Compiling an existing codebase with VS 2019 suggests the declspec(align()) directives are now silently ignored. Has anyone seen this documented anywhere?

alignas has certain restrictions compared to declspec(align()) so it's not trivial to move a codebase over to using it.

1. Doesn't work for typedefs
2. It's a bit picky where the attribute goes in the variable declaration - compared to declspec.

Comment: _"VS 2019 suggests the declspec(align()) directives are now silently ignored."_ Can you share how this is suggested?

Comment: Can you show a [mcve] where `__declspec(align(...))` is ignored?

Comment: `struct aaa { unsigned char bbb[12][8]; }; __declspec(align(256)) struct aaa yyy;`

Comment: The code above should show the problem. Run dumpbin /section:.bss on the obj file and the alignment is only 8B with VS 2019. But 256B with VS 2013, as I would expect

Comment: I did not find any documentation about VS compiler ignoring `__declspec(align(...))`. I suggest that you could submit this question to [Microsoft DC](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html). Besides, I suggest that you could use `struct __declspec(align(256)) aaa {unsigned char bbb[12][8];};`.